# Replacing a compact fluorescent bulb in a bathroom exhaust fan with an LED bulb?

Tags: light, fans, exhaust

I have a bathroom exhaust fan that has a built-in light that is a compact fluorescent bulb. It does not provide sufficient lighting (2400 lumens) and they do not produce a replacement bulb that is brighter. My idea is to remove this light and associated ballast from the assembly, rewire it to accept a 65 or higher LED light bulb. Are there any reasons why I can’t or should not do this? A specific question I have is whether it is acceptable to put an LED bulb inside a closed assembly from the perspective of heat build-up. Thanks to anyone who responds.

Comment: 65? What units?

Comment: 2400 lumens is quite a bit of light. Are you sure it's not just got a dirty lens or something else reducing the light a bunch? Also those CFL tubes tend to get quite a bit dimmer as they get older.

Comment: I will second cleaning of the lens.  The inside near the light can collect dust/dirt/bugs over time, and nobody bothers to clean them until the bulb burns out and need replacing, if even then.  It is usually just replace the bulb ASAP.

Comment: Sorry, 9Watts or 65 watts equivalent.No, the light was low since it was installed. Also, I replaced the original bulb a couple of years ago with no difference.

Comment: Got a pic of the actual bulb?

Comment: @crip659 if the lens is plastic, it can change over time.  My own bathroom fixture had a white plastic cover, and it turned yellow and more opaque.  This is particularly a problem with CFL bulbs since they have a lot of UV output.  I just leave mine off now.  If I ever get tired of the look I'll just replace the entire fixture.

Answer (score 5):

Regarding your specific question: the bulb itself will be rated for enclosed operation if it is capable of such. Most high-wattage LED bulbs are not rated for enclosed operation.

Comment: Thanks. I just checked the box of a Phillips A19 14 W LED bulb and it is says suitable for “enclosed luminaries”.

Comment: What type CFL does it use precisely? That Philips bulb may not make any more lumens. It's rated for 1500 and some four-tube CFLs come in at that amount. If it's a two-tube there's a nice 1100 lumen color selectable LED drop-in unit that Feit makes as well, which given the reflector design of common CFL fixtures might get just as much light in the room. You might want to give it a try as an 'easy button' option.

Answer (score 5):

If it is truly a *compact fluorescent* then there is no separate ballast, no rewiring, and this is a simple bulb replacement.

How can you tell? If the bulb *unscrews* to expose an Edison base, has a large plastic base above the base, and (usually, not *always*) has a curled tube/bulb [like this example from Amazon](https://amzn.to/3TsKUoI):

[image: Edison base cfl]

then it is a compact fluorescent or CFL. There are also some others, such as [this 4-pin CFL from Amazon](https://amzn.to/3TuuFr2):

[image: 4-pin cfl]

If it doesn't look like one of those, then you may have a regular fluorescent bulb with a separate ballast, which would require rewiring, etc.

But if it is a CFL then generally speaking you want to match with an LED that is the same or lower power consumption (because power --> heat) and the desired light (Lumens).

For example, if it is a 13W CFL rated for 900 Lumens then look for an LED with the same base type *and* 13W or less power *and* more Lumens. A typical 13W LED (same power) might produce 1150 Lumens (27% more light). There are a lot of variations depending on brand, quality, etc.

Comment: Yes, the existing bulb is a 4 pin CFL as you have shown.

Comment: @Tom I have quite of few of those replaced, although not in a bathroom but in tabletop lamps and similar. If disassembly is not too difficult, you might want to grab a cheap one from Ali just to try first and have a more reliable (but more expensive and specifying enclosed operation) one at hand when the cheapo inevitably breaks. CFL is already more efficient than an incandescent, so the wattage difference will be less pronounced.

Comment: Thanks - some good suggestions

Answer (score 0):

If you replace the socket with an Edison, you have to mount it securely as well as wire it, and you won't know if you have enough light until you've done all that.  Given the 4 pin socket and the presumed age of the fan motor, I would recommend replacing the whole unit and be done with it.  (If you get one with an Edison socket, you can easily increase the light level as needed, assuming the enclosure is so rated.)

Comment: Thanks for the advice, particularly the part about replacing the whole fan/light unit although my enthusiasm for doing this right now is not high.

Comment: I can appreciate that.  It may be easier than you think, though:  shut off the power, remove the cover and mounting screws and the vent clamp (if any), and pull it out.  Take it to the store and look for something pretty close (and definitely no larger!).  Bring it home and pop it in, etc.  And be glad you're not standing on a chair trying to kludge the Edison in there!  Oh, and don't forget the duct tape!

Comment: If it's a Broan or NuTone, there's a decent chance you can mount a newer unit in the same housing with the same duct. They have a very helpful tech support like that can tell you if it's a possibility. You may also be able to exchange the light assembly for an LED integrated one.